# Is there a way to automatically create doc for classes and Methods in OpenEdge Developer Studio?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

OpenEdge Developer Studio is built on Eclipse where usually the shortcut Ctrl+Alt+J can be used to create JavaDoc for classes and methods.

For Progress however I am unable to figure out how this should work.

Could someone help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

To create an html documentation (like http://help.consultingwerkcloud.com/smartcomponent_library/release/) use this here:

https://github.com/Riverside-Software/pct/wiki/ClassDocumentation
https://github.com/Riverside-Software/pct/wiki/HtmlDocumentation

For documentation comments in PDSOE, I'd suggest you have a look at:

https://www.hh-berlin.de/oedt/features/editor

It's going to be commercial. I'm beta-testing it since a while. And it's working really, really nice.